# How to show the specific push notification only in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We know that IPhone has a push notification function. 
But I have different kinds of notification and want the user can set which one they want.

For example, facebook can set message, wall posts, events, comments, etc...

I want to do something like this. But I'm no idea how to do it.
Can I push the notification to a phone, then the iphone can find out what message it is and decide to show or not show?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You (ie your server) have to filter them for the client.
When the user updates his filter, you update the database entry on your server.

And then you only send them the notifications they want. No chance for filtering on the phone. 
Your app might not be launched when the notifications arrive.